# I have a wrong gravatar

Tags: support, gravatar, openid

I've been having a fight with my login this days (my OpenID provider was broken), claimed my account with my email addres, had some problems, then finally logged in with my OpenID (when my provider came back) and now I have a gravatar that doesn't match the one registered with my email address, just a default...

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your profile is using the anonymous identicon. To switch to Gravatar, go to [your profile's edit page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/81974) and click "change picture".

Comment: Uoooh! Super!
Seems like it went crazy... Thanks!